# OperationalError at /products/ no such column: products_product.default_shop_id

Tags: django

admin.py
    from django.contrib import admin

```
# Register your models here.


from .models import Product, ProductImage, Category, ProductFeatured,      color_product, size_product

admin.site.register(Product)

admin.site.register(ProductImage)

admin.site.register(Category)


admin.site.register(ProductFeatured)

admin.site.register(color_product)

admin.site.register(size_product)
```

Problem is i have deleted the database and recreate it...i have no model name shop, and not even in admin.py
then why
 its still in admin side and showing shops app...but when i clcik on it it says no such table exist.
and when i click on products it gives me operational error

```
OperationalError at /products/
no such column: products_product.default_shop_id
```

[image]

Comment: How did you recreate tables?

Comment: sorry ..i mean i changed my models.py file and then again did makemigrations and then migrate ..to solve this error ...but why its still showing shops....